How to use KPI cards effectively to showcase comparison for month over month analysis?
I have been finding it difficult to use KPI cards effectively. There are so many types that can be explored to show valuable comparison for month over month or yoy data. I'm a beginner and still learning BI. I understand you have to use DAX to work this out but I'd like to know key step by step process to execute the data. Data set I am currently using is fuel consumption and co2 emission data of aircrafts. Due to sensitivity and confidential data unable to share here. Any tips are well appreciated.
Frankly I haven't tried yet as I'd like to understand the basic steps for comparison for KPI cards. Something that shows the data vs previous month and year than the KPI data stats alone.

Welcome to [SO]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We help solve specific problem with code you are writing, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [what you are asking] page for details on how to best help us help you.

if the data is sensitive, then please provide some dummy data that has the same data structure as your real data. What's more, pls also provide the expected output.
